# debugging my program I'm getting max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, debugging, count, range, max

I'm getting max() arg is an empty sequence. I'm not very sure what to do with it, and I also want to know if there is any other problems besides that one.

```
#getting file as input

print "Enter file name"

file1=raw_input()

#try block

try:

    error_to_catch=FileNotFoundError

#catching file not found exception

except NameError:

        error_to_catch=IOError

#opening file

fName = open(file1)

#initialising variables

sVal, totnumbers = 0, 0

#loop statement for n values

for line_number, line in enumerate(fName):

    numValues = map(int, line.split())

    #calculating sum

    sVal += sum(numValues)

    totnumbers += len(numValues)

#printing results

print "fileName",file1   

print "sum",sVal

print "count:", totnumbers

print "Average:", 1.0*s/totnumbers

#min max calculation

a=max(numValues)

b=min(numValues)

r=a-b

print "maximum",a

print "minimum",b

print "Range",r

value=raw_input('would you like to continue:')

if value=='Y':

    print "Enter file name"

    file1=raw_input()

else:

        print"good bye"
```

Comment: Is the file empty or are you iterating over the file twice by any chance?

Comment: I'm very confused what you're trying to do with that try, except block.

Comment: Actually I think your problem is `numValues = map(int, line.split())` you only ever store the last value outside the loop which is most likely called on a empty line so you get a `[]` as output

Comment: I tried to write it as list(map(int,input().split())) but I keep getting everything zero.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the input file?